# How to set input type date value of max="variable value"

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Not able to get "today Date value to "max" attribute of input field", but able to fetch the value in the console.

Would you guys help me how to get value in the input field (i.e max="2018-08-21")

```
var todayDate =
      new Date().getFullYear() +
      "-" +
      ("0" + (new Date().getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
      "-" +
      ("0" + new Date().getDate()).slice(-2);
    console.log(todayDate, "here");
```

```html
 <div class="input-group">
    <input type="date" max="todayDate" />
 </div>
```

Comment: You Javascript should be before HTML

Comment: You should use `momentjs` when you work with dates.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using Angular you can bind `max` with date as:

**TS**

```
todayDate = new Date().getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (new Date().getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + new Date().getDate()).slice(-2);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="date" [max]="todayDate" />
</div>
```

You can check stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-max-date)

Comment: @MalathyVenkatesan great you can upvote & accept answer :)

Answer (score 0):

use `[max]`

```
export class AppComponent  {

  todayDate = new Date('2018-08-21')

}

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="date" [max]="todayDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no-one is providing you with an Angular answer and instead rely on your locale to test it (which is dangerous to do), here it is : a custom validator that will check if the date is below the one you give to the validator. [Here is a stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7iffwa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

The validator :

```
export function notAfterToday(date: Date = new Date(Date.now())): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    const selectedDate = new Date(control.value);
    return selectedDate && !isNaN(selectedDate.getTime()) && selectedDate.getTime() > date.getTime() ? { 'dateTooHigh': true } : null;
  };
```